# Is 12.10 ready from prime time?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, wubi

I recently installed 12.10 - dual boot using Wubi. I had numerous stability problems: many sporadic, unaccounted for system errors, software that was installed and then seemed to disappear from App Launcher, etc.

Machine is new HP quad with 4 gig memory - wonderful piece of hardware - definitely no hardware problems there.

I went back to 12.04 (installed from ISO image, not Wubi) and it's rock solid - never any issues at all.

New to Linux/Ubuntu after 20 years on MS/Windows and loving it - I develop in C++ and Python - maybe will try Lazarus since I know Delphi. Would like to use the latest and greatest Ubuntu but I will not sacrifice stabilty.

Are there known stabilty problems with 12.10?
Would using the standard install instead of Wubi help?

Seems a lot of users are voting down this question - not sure why since other users have confirmed problems.

Comment: 12.10 is ready for prime time. Since  October 18, it has been stable version. Maybe, Wubi is causing these problems, so I advice you to install Ubuntu 12.10 without Wubi.

Comment: I'm having the sporadic system errors on both my machines as well since 12.10. Sadly I have to say it's the most unreliable Ubuntu I've ever had :-( I didn't use Wubi so I think that's not the problem.

Comment: Wubi is not intended to be used as a final installation, it is for you to try Ubuntu see if you like it and do the full install, so you can't really compare, of course it should work mostly fine and problem free, else report the bugs. 12.10 has been receiving updates *ever since it's release* it will receive more as always. LTS releases are meant to be stable, so if you want stability use the LTS.

Comment: @Nanne - thanks for the help but this really is not a question about 'debugging issues'. It is a question about the stability of this release. I do have enough experience with systems to know when there may be a fundamental problem.  I see at least one other user has also confirmed problems with this release. That is the thrust of my question.

Comment: Maybe I was just trying to find something in your question that would render it ontopic on this Q&A site. Your last edit made it a bit better, but I would still try and make this a more specific question. You question comes close to what is listed in the faq: http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask (under "don't ask"), so I was trying to steer it towards something more specific.

Comment: @Nanne - understood - thanks. I am not ranting or anything like that. Just trying to find out if maybe there are problems with Wubi or generally instability that has been reported with 12.10.

Comment: I also noticed that apps I install through software centre go straight onto the Unity launcher, but are not there on reboot. Just run them again, right click on app in launcher and select `lock to launcher`. Not sure it's a big enough issue to affect the 'prime time'. Wubi isn't responsible. Why do you think it would? (It's not that mysterious)

Comment: @bcbc - I have no real reason to think that Wubi would make a difference - just shooting in the dark - all new to me - just getting oriented with Unbuntu/Linux. But what you mentioned was one of the things I noticed - apps were not on launcher after re-boot. Did figure out how to fix it. But a lot times I just got error messages 'Ubuntu has experienced a system error' etc. That was few weeks ago - since then I have gotten more oriented and realized that the launcher stuff is a stupid issue but it just led me to questions about 12.10 in general - is it just stupid bugs or something deeper.

Comment: @Mikey there are issues. Most I'd classify as irritations but some can result in loss of work e.g. blank screen after suspend (on my 12.04 install). You can look at open bugs in launchpad.net to get an idea. It's not surprising since it's a different model (open source, independent developers, free apps, low or no budget) compared to e.g. Apple/Microsoft.

Comment: @bcbc - Have not had any problems at all with 12.04. I am not complaining. As I am becoming familiar with the Linux way of doing things, being a geek I like it better than all the hand-holding you get with MS.

Comment: -1 Not a real question, voting to close. Plus, 'Is Ubuntu ready *from* prime time' what does that even mean? If you need stability install 12.04LTS and forget wubi. Good luck, whatever you choose to run.

Comment: @Tom - Of course it's a 'real question'. Read again.

Comment: @Mikey I probably owe you a better explanation then. It's a reason for close-voting, [explained in the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#close). I believe it meets the community's definition of 'Not a real question'(specifically the overly broad & vague parts) and so voted accordingly. In plain English sure it is a real question, but it isn't a good fit here on this site.

Comment: Ubuntu has been ready from prime time since a couple of versions ago.

Comment: Comparing Wubi to normal install....
Is like comparing the moon with cheese....
It may look like it, but it isnt really cheese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled 12.10 from the CD, it upgraded my 12.04 installation to 12.10 and everything has been working smoothly - 12.10 appears to be solid and fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same computer setup (Quad 4 ,4 gigs, etc.). There is a stable problem with Wubi and 12.10. It Crashes alot, it is the most unstable version i've ever seen in Ubuntu , since 10.04 Lts. Maybe if we wait, since it is new, the updates might fix the problem and with all those people reporting bugs too. But do we need a Combo Bios? Like windows and Linux combo bios , or one or the other? I am running 12.10 on a windows Bios along with Wubi. The Ubuntu OS is in a windows Folder. Like a Cloud , but not. 12.04 won't detect my monitor. But 12.10 will. Just some thoughts.

Comment: I'm sticking with 12.04 LTS meanwhile. No problems at all with that version. I installed from CD and its on it's own partition.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.10 STS(Known For new feature and innovation) is latest version after the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(Known for its stability).
As the name describes..
Try to be with the stable systems rather than new features untill it get mature

Comment: What... is STS?

Comment: @UriHerrera: "Standard Term Support", used by various software. Have never seen Ubuntu use it. From the Google of it it seems to be mainly a term used in the Spanish milieu when it comes to Ubuntu.